# Ordered vs sequence in association in UML

Tags: uml, class-design, class-diagram, object

I am trying to understand UML class diagrams.

Imagine two classes that are related with each other by association. What is the difference between `{ordered}` and `{sequence}` for the association?

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering Stack Exchange... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: Welcome on SE !  Your question is indeed very interesting and there's little clear info about this topic. Even in the UML specs.  Maybe you could add a diagram to illustrate your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short

`{sequence}` means `{ordered, nonunique}`

#### In long

Your question addresses indeed a very subtle difference in the UML semantics associated to [multiplicity](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html):

- `ordered` means that the objets are ordered in the collection of associated elements.  This means that there is a mapping between a positive integer to the elements in the collection.  It doesn't say more, and in particular, it doesn't say if the elements in the associated collection are `unique` or not.
- `sequence` or `seq` means that the association implements an *ordered bag*, that is an ordered collection of elements where the same elements may occur several times (example:  a trip made of a sequence of towns : *New-York -> Chicago -> New-York -> Los-Angeles -> New-York* ).

#### And longer

In an UML model, association-ends have two possible properties: `isOrdered` and `isUnique`.  The `ordered` implies that `isOrdered = true` (explicitely specified).  For `sequence`, you can deduce from the text that it's `isOrdered = true` and `isUnique` = `false`.

Table 7.1 of the UML 2.5.1 specification shows the following relationship:

```
     isOrdered   isUnique        Type of collection 
       false      true           Set
       true       false          OrderedSet
       false      true           Bag
       true       false          Sequence
```

But the UML specifications do not explain much about the type of collection.  I think that it is a concept which main purpose is to align the UML on the OCL semantics (OCL being the language that can be used to formally describe the constraints in UML).  I don't see a clear advantage in terms of expressivity of the model itself.

Furthermore, the specifications uses its own terminology inconsistently, since the text body explicitly says that the *sequence* means an *ordered bag*.

Therefore I'd advise to avoid the `{sequence}` and prefer `{ordered`, `nonunique`} instead, which is unambiguous and language neutral.

Comment: You have made an error in copying the table. a `Bag` should be a non-unique collection and an `OrderedSet` is a unique collection.